# Find the area of a bounding polygon that encloses a set of points

Tags: python, bounding-box, polygons

I have a series of points on a plot of the sky. I want to find the area that these points occupy.

To do this I need to find the vertices of a polygon that encloses these points - convert the points to an equal-area projection and then work out the area.

I have all the code written apart from how to calculate the vertices of a polygon that enclose the points on the graph. What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: There is no python in this question

Comment: One way to find a convex-polygon that contains these points is to compute the convex-hull. Look up the convex hull algorithm.

Comment: You could look into the convex hull algorithms. They can be used for determining the smallest polygon that encloses all of them. Look at this: http://geomalgorithms.com/a10-_hull-1.html

Comment: If the image in the question is correct, there are multiple solutions. How do you know which you want?

Comment: Why are the green spheres not connected?

Comment: The dashed polygonal boundary represents a concave hull which is not the same as a convex hull.  I would begin your search for that term, whether you wish to generate the container for the centroid of the circles or their actual bounds.  Convex hull searches will be fruitless unless the desired outcome is modified.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is finding a convex hull for a given set of points. That doc desrcibes it pretty well:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html

Comment: The reference is for a convex hull, unfortunately the polygonal area delineated is for a concave hull, which is different and not as easy to calculate.

Comment: This question and the algorithms mentioned seem relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268547/estimating-an-area-of-an-image-generated-by-a-set-of-points-alpha-shapes

Answer (score 3):

The polygon you chose is not convex, so the popular convex hull algorithm wouldn't work for you.

https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/ seems what you want