# Generate convex hull from points

Tags: hive, gis, esri, convex-hull

I have a Hive table with many thousands of points.  The only columns are latitude|longitude.  I know in advance that these points are all in a certain area, and the extreme outer edge of the points does form a continuous polygon, but many of the points are interior.  I'm trying to determine which points are the external convex hull for visualization.  I don't want to use all points, because it has messy interior holes that don't look good on a visualization.  I'm using hive-1.2.1000.2.4.2.0.  Here's what I tried:

```
hive> add jar /home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/esri-geometry-api.jar;
Added [/home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/esri-geometry-api.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/esri-geometry-api.jar]
hive> add jar /home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar;
Added [/home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar]
hive> create temporary function ST_ConvexHull AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_ConvexHull';
OK
Time taken: 0.014 seconds
hive> create temporary function ST_AsText AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_AsText';
OK
Time taken: 0.009 seconds
hive> create temporary function ST_Point AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Point';
OK
Time taken: 0.009 seconds
hive> SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Point(latitude, longitude))) FROM sandbox11.cnst_zn;
```

I have also tried flipping latitude and longitude order in my query.  In both instances, I get 'MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY' as the response.  The documentation of the UDF is here: https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Operations#st_convexhull

Comment: You may find some of the ideas on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41268547/752843) to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the convex hull of the geometries of all the multiple records of a table, use [ST_Aggr_ConvexHull](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Operations#st_aggr_convexhull) rather than ST_ConvexHull (which expects a list of multiple geometries from a single row).

[collaborator]

Update: the syntax for aggregate ConvexHull would be similar to the syntax for aggregate Union, for which we have [an example in an article](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/16/st_geometry-aggregate-functions-for-hive-in-spatial-framework-for-hadoop/).

Comment: Hi Randall Whitman, thanks as always for the help.  What is this UDF expecting?  I have 2 columns, latitude, longitude.  Should I concat with a comma, or reverse order or anything like that?

Comment: You would create each point with ST_Point, like ST_Point(longitude, latitude).